# How to capture an image of Azure virtual machine in new portal?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, clone

I have a bizsparkplus subscription. I followed the below link but could not find the capture button:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-capture-image/#next-steps

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking through the comments in the link you mentioned, it looks like it is not possible  to do so in the  new portal as of today. You will need to use Azure PowerShell Cmdlets. You can find more details about the procedure here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

Until yesterday, I found nothing in **Azure's new portal** that can help capture an image from a VM,

**but today**, out of the blue, I found a "Capture" button right inside the VM's Overview tab :) (will appear only for VMs with "Managed Disks")

[image]

It is super easy to capture an image (takes like a minute), but you have to connect ssh on the VM first & run this command (which will delete user's home folder) as per [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image):

```
sudo waagent -deprovision+user -force
```

then you can use the button.

**-- Warning --**

Capturing an image from your VM will stop it and mark it as **generalized** which won't let you start this VM **ever again**, because being **generalized** is [an irreversible process "by design"](https://github.com/azure/azure-powershell/issues/1978#issuecomment-199805666)! .. the Sh***y thing is, they didn't even put a warning on the button!, so be careful with that!

Comment: Any way to save data in the home directory? thats is where all the software in the machine actually is. Where do they actually want people to store their software?

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting the home directory is the core behind generalizing the VM to take the image, so you can't use it. For me I saved the sources in `/usr/sources/` and other repos and stuff like that inside `/var/`

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not available yet in the new Azure Portal. You have to options : Azure Resource explorer or PowerShell.

Here is an example in powershell. In this example the custom image will be saved in the VM storage account. The vm custom image will be stored in the following location "System/Microsoft.Compute/Images/templates/***.vhd". :

```
$vmResourceGroup = "iaas-rg";
$vmName = "ubuntu";
$destinationContainerName = "templates";
$vhdNamePrefix = "template";
$sampleOutupTemplatePath =  "C:\Templates\ImagesGeneralized\sampleOutputTemplateUbuntu.json";

Login-AzureRmAccount

#Dellocate the VM
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroup -Name $vmName

#Generalize the vm 
Set-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroup -Name $vmName -Generalized

# Save the custom vm Image
Save-AzureRmVMImage -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroup -VMName $vmName -DestinationContainerName $destinationContainerName -VHDNamePrefix $vhdNamePrefix -Path $sampleOutupTemplatePath
```

The second option is to use [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), you can execute the operations manually * :

[image]

*To execute those operations, the mode "read/write" must be selected in Azure Resource Explorer.

Regards,

Comment: I have captured the image and try to create vm from this image using power shell. The point that I stuck in is to assign NetworkInterfaceId. When I tried the following comment $vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id I got the  Property id  at path 'properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id' is invalid. Do you have any idea how to set interface id?

Comment: is your $nic successfully created before to assign it to the VM ?

Comment: I copied the $Nic from other resource and just change the storage name at the end. It is now ok. Thank you.

Comment: Your are welcome ! Mark the answer as resolved if it's ok for you !

Answer (score 1):

You can able to capture the classic virtual machines in new portal. There is an option for capturing. attaching is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I am using the new portal with Resouce Group. It is not classic VM.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else looking for this topic, I was researching it and found some azure docs here:

[Create a managed image of a generalized VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource)

which explains generalizing is a one way operation (and why)

and how to deal with that by creating a VM copy first

[Create a Windows VM from a specialized disk by using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#option-3-copy-an-existing-azure-vm)

Using the option 3 in the article.